# Why is a set inclusion true regarding the maximum likelihood estimator?

Tags: statistics, optimization

The following doubt regards a step of a proof of consistency of the maximum likelihood estimator in the case of independent NON identically distributed random variables.

Assume the parameter space is given by $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$, denote the maximum likelihood estimator on a sample of $n$ INID random variables $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$, that have probability densities respectively $f_1(y; \theta) , \dots, f_n(y;\theta)  $,  by $\hat{\theta}_n$ and the true parameter value $\theta_0$ .

The maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ in this framework is taken to be the value that maximizes (for simplicity let's assume it exists) $$\ln \prod_{i= 1 }^n  f_i(Y_i; \theta)$$

Define $\Omega(\eta) := \Omega \setminus B(\theta_0, \eta) $ where $B(a,r)$ is the open ball centered at $a$ of radius $r$ and $\eta > 0$. Define
$$R_n^* = \sup_{\theta} \{ \ln \prod_{i= 1 }^n [ f_i(Y_i; \theta) / f_i( Y_i; \theta_0)  ] : \theta \in \Omega(\eta)   \}$$

I want to prove that $\{ \hat{\theta}_n \in \Omega(\eta)  \} \subset \{ R_n^* \ge 0   \}$ , how can this be seen?

Comment: We know that the function $$ function(\theta)=\log \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{f_i(Y_i;\theta)}{f_i(Y_i;\theta_0)}\right)$$ evaluated at $\theta=\hat{\theta}_n$ is greater than or equal to its value when evaluated at $\theta=\theta_0$ (by definition of $\hat{\theta}_n$ as the global optimum of this function over $\Omega$), and $function(\theta_0)=0$.  The function evaluated at $\hat{\theta}_n$ is the same as $R_n^*$ in the case $\hat{\theta}_n \in \Omega(\eta)$. Optimizing the function over a smaller domain does not change the optimum when the global optimizer is already in that domain.

Comment: @Michael thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write my comment as an answer: Define $g:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$ g(\theta) = \log \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{f_i(Y_i;\theta)}{f_i(Y_i;\theta_0)}\right)$$
By definition of $\hat{\theta}_n$ as the global maximizer of $g(\theta)$ over all $\theta \in \Omega$ (and since $\theta_0\in \Omega$) we have
$$ g(\hat{\theta}_n) \geq g(\theta_0)=0$$
Now $R_n^*$ is the maximum of $g(\theta)$ over a restricted domain.  But if $\hat{\theta}_n$ is already in that restricted domain, then $R_n^*=g(\hat{\theta}_n)$ and hence $R_n^*\geq 0$.